# How to handle REST API based on user role

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am creating a project that have two user roles, `basic` and `partner` users.

I have the end point `/api/stores/:storeid/appointments`

if the requester is `basic` user then this will send available appointments timings
if the requester is `partner` user then this will send requested appointments timings and should be able to modify them

keeping in mind each request has its own calculations and queries to send back data.

what i am thinking is to establish a new route like,

`/api/partners/stores/:storeid/appointments`

so i can process requests differently

is this a valid way of doing things or I should only have one route to the resource ?
then conditionally query and process the request

Comment: Getting the appointments can be the same endpoint, but since partner only can modify, then you create another endpoint for that and inside. I would create a middleware to authorize the partner.

Comment: yea I understand your point, but my problem is when it is a get request and user is basic i am only sending available times in an array of strings but when user is partner i am sending the entire object this is where my uncertainty coming from

Comment: Are you sending the user details on the request? If so, you should consider using an authentication package like passport.js, you can define your login process there. The user details will be saved on a cookie and after authentication the user details will always be on the request

Comment: JWT tokens, you can store the access rights basic or partner within the token. This way if you add the middleware to your route you will be able to verify that the user is logged in and their access rights on every request.